# is it possible to get signal strength and channels of a wifi?

Tags: ios, wifi

for Android, several apps exist that show such information, like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer does it:

[image]

I need similar functionality in my iOS app but can't find any information about that. It this forbidden by Apple?

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't allow apps to access the hardware like that. A fairly common workaround is to measure network throughput instead. You could take periodic samples of the current network speed, and then display that data over time.

[Network Multimeter](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/network-multimeter/id518835474?mt=8), for example, is an app that will give you info on your network as you walk around. It does that by sending data across the network and displaying the throughput.